# replace the text by mapping the respective pandas values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing old and new, i need to replace the old with respective new value of dataframe df to a text, please help me on mapping the correct values from this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'old':['following', 'certain', 'godwil_5708'],
                  'new':['the below', 'confidently yes', 'godwil']})
```

text

```
text = "my text contains of the 33109 following values RT3123SO55 and also with certain numbers godwil_5708 and 323stwe and 8y9yc2 456453"
```

Expected output:

```
'my text contains of the 33109 the below values RT3123SO55 and also with confidently yes numbers godwil and 323stwe and 8y9yc2 456453'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
for a,b in zip(l["old"].values,l["new"].values):
    text=text.replace(a,b)
print(text)
```

Output:
my text contains of the 33109 the below values RT3123SO55 and also with confidently yes numbers godwil and 323stwe and 8y9yc2 456453

Answer (score 1):

Convert your dataframe to a dict then replace values from `old` (keys) to `new` (values) with `re` module:

```
d = df.set_index('old')['new'].to_dict()
t = re.sub(fr"(?P<old>{'|'.join(d)})", lambda x: d[x.group('old')], text)
```

Output:

```
>>> t
'my text contains of the 33109 the below values RT3123SO55 and also with confidently yes numbers godwil and 323stwe and 8y9yc2 456453'
```